# Showstopping bug in Excel Online that breaks all add-ins

Tags: excel-online

Also submitted here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2940

Starting October 31st, 2022 (Halloween Special):
Any Excel spreadsheet open in Excel Online gets stripped of settings saved in it before. This renders useless all plug-ins that use Office.context.document.settings.set(key, value).

**Expected Behavior**

Settings saved by Excel add-ins in the property bag of an Excel spreadsheet should be retained on reopening the spreadsheet in Excel Online.

**Current Behavior**

Any settings saved by an Excel add-in when open in Excel Online get deleted the next time the document is opened.
This functionality works correctly in Excel for Mac and Excel for Windows (all desktop versions of Excel).

**Steps to Reproduce, or Live Example**

1. Side-load the following add-in to Excel Online: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/office-add-in-save-custom-settings
2. Use 'create setting' button to create a setting in the Property Bag.
   Read it back using the 'Get setting' button to make sure it was stored:
   [image: Screenshot 2022-11-02 at 01 09 36]
3. Reload the browser page
4. Use 'Get setting' button to retieve the saved property by name.
   It returns null:
   [image: screenshot 2]

**Additional details**

For all spreadsheets containing add-in settings, if you open a spreadsheet in Excel Online, it automatically removes the 'webextensions' folder from the file deleting all the settings saved there.
Before opening the spreadsheet in Excel Online:
[image: screenshot 3]
After opening the spreadsheet in Excel Online:
[image: screenshot 4]

**Your Environment**

Platform [PC desktop, Mac, iOS, Office Online]: Office Online
Host [Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.]: Excel
Office version number: current
Operating System: MacOS
Browser (if using Office Online): Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as of November 3rd, 2022 the bug has been fixed and properties are retained in Excel Online.